# Trying to create a simple applet but it won't run through the whole program

Tags: java, applet, textfield

I'm creating an applet and all that happens is it opens displays "How many genres are there?" and then a textField appears. i enter a number and hit enter but nothing ever happens! (i dont get any errors but nothing happens)

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class appletPracticw extends Applet implements ActionListener { 
TextField numG;
TextField g ;
TextField numS; 
TextField sog; 
private int number;
private int numberOfSongs;
String gener;
String songName;
public void go(){
    numG= new TextField(5);
    numS= new TextField(5);
    g= new TextField(5);
    sog= new TextField(5);
    numG.addActionListener(this);
    g.addActionListener(this);
    sog.addActionListener(this);
    numS.addActionListener(this);
    Tracker t=new Tracker();
    add(new Label("How many genres are there? "));  add(numG);
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        catogories c=new catogories();
        add(new Label("Name of genere: "));  add(g);
        t.addCatogory(c,gener);
    }
    for(int x=0;x<number;x++){
        add(new Label("How many songs are there in "+t.getCatogories().get(x).getGenere()));  add(numS);
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfSongs;i++){
            Songs s=new Songs();
            add(new Label("The name of song "+(i+1)+" is"));  add(sog);
            t.getCatogories().get(x).addSong(s, songName);
        }
    }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==numG){
        String num=numG.getText();
        number=Integer.parseInt(num);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==numS){
        String num=numS.getText();
        numberOfSongs=Integer.parseInt(num);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==g){
        gener=g.getText();
    }
    if(e.getSource()==sog){
        songName=sog.getText();
    }
}
public void init() {
    go();
```

}
    public appletPracticw() {

}
}

Comment: *"Trying to create a simple applet.."*  'simple applet' is a tautology.  See [Why should CS teachers stop teaching applets?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196499/why-should-cs-teachers-stop-teaching-applets) for details. Code a Swing based frame if you want 'simple'.

Answer (score 2):

The field `number` is initialized with the value `0`.

You build the applet, adding labels and text fields. It looks like you are assuming that the program waits for a user input at this line:

```
add(new Label("How many genres are there? "));  add(numG);
```

In reality it is just creating the user interface and doesn't wait for inputs.

So the two `for` loops are executed, but as `number` is still `0`, the loops are never entered.

What you should do instead is perform the actual action (in your case this is changing the GUI by adding new labels and fields) in the `actionPerformed` method, so that category labels and input fields are created **after** the user has entered the number of genres. The same must be done for the second loop, too.

Comment: wait i can't extend 2 classes.

Comment: @LouisB you're welcome, I hope you got the point. The reason why the `ActionListener` is used at all, is that user input can be done at any time and your program needs to react somehow to it.

Comment: wait but i still dont understand how to initialize a basic structure and then after something happened to continue? like should i put my for loop's in the actionlistner?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say because I don't know exactly what the purpose of your whole application or website is. And sorry, "extending the ActionListener" was misleading - I just meant you should do the actual action (e.g., showing new Labels and InputFields) in the `actionPerformed` method. You should write down a plan to define how you want your screen change after which inputs. I don't know what else you want to do in your applet, but what I see right now could be done much easier with HTML and a bit of JavaScript.